# "Operation failed. No files" when download a file

Tags: javascript, html, css, file, download

I need help solving a problem I was having while developing my website.

I'm trying to insert a download link in my website with a PDF file to download.

The problem arises when I press the Download button, the download starts but the browser gives me an error, namely, "Operation failed. No file".

I read on the internet that it could be a permissions problem (?)

This is the 'a' tag I wrote to insert the link

```
<a class="download_file" download href="/website/static/docs/CV.pdf">Download CV</a>
```

Could anyone help me solve this problem? I wish the file could be downloaded without problems.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `download` and click the link? I'm 90% sure you just have the wrong URL

Comment: Have you checked the path to the file? or try a different browser there might be a security issue

Comment: @Djave I tried and it sends me to a page that says "Not found" but it seems impossible to me since the path I wrote is correct

Comment: What is the document root in the website server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, I managed to solve the problem, I just changed the 'href' attribute like this:

```
<a class="download_file" download href="{{ url_for('static',filename='docs/CV.pdf') }}">Download CV</a>
```

Anyway, thanks to everyone who replied